# jq - replace some variables in array

Tags: json, bash, jq

This question is caused due to [nomad behaviour](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/698#issuecomment-327643977)

I have an json like this:

```
# cat test.json 
{
  "Name": "test",
  "TaskGroups": [
    {
      "Name": "test1",
      "Count": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "test2",
      "Count": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "test3",
      "Count": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "test4",
      "Count": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "test5",
      "Count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to change it like this:
1) add "Job" in front of my json - I can do it with

```
# cat test.json | jq '{"Job": .}'
```

2) replace "Count" variable for multiple items in array, like test1 and test5, I can do it like this:

```
# cat test.json | jq ' .TaskGroups[0,4].Count = 0 '
```

I can run both commands as whole thing and it works fine like this:

```
# cat test.json | jq ' .TaskGroups[0,4].Count = 0 | {"Job": .} '
```

But also I want to search for variables I want to change by their names, not by their number in array. So I can do something like this:

```
cat test.json | jq ' .TaskGroups[] | select(.Name == ("test1", "test5")).Count = 0 '
```

But because of I am listing array, not whole json - I am loosing some variables and "Job:", that I just added. Or I can add it to the every item in my array.
So how I can change variable by its name and also add "Job:" at the same time?

Comment: Side note : consider using `jq command file` instead of `cat file | jq command`

Comment: Thank you, I used this for example and tests. There will be command like "curl | jq | curl -x POST"

Comment: hm, I see some mistakes in my question: 1st - I was talking about "test1 and test2", but thinking of test1 and test5; 2nd - I assumed test1 as number 0 in array, that is correct, and test5 as number 5 in array, that is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `|=` "update-assignment" operator with the following syntax :

```
(.TaskGroups[] | select(.Name == ("test1", "test5")).Count) |= 0 | {Job : . }
```

It is documented [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=).

I've been able to successfully test it on jqplay : https://jqplay.org/s/578mkUAklU

Comment: Yes, it works fine both with test json and with real json from nomad, thank you very much.